# Unable to create subdirectory in a directory for which I have group permissions

Tags: permissions, debian

OK, this has been asked [before](https://superuser.com/questions/665057/group-member-cannot-create-files-directories-in-folder) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/168428/linux-group-permissions-not-being-enforced-correctly), but none of the answers are working for me, so I'm asking again....

My username is `tullyc`, and according to `groups` I have permissions for the `tomcat` group.

```
$ groups
tullyc tomcat
```

and `id` agrees:

```
$ id
uid=1005(tullyc) gid=1005(tullyc) groups=1005(tullyc),1003(tomcat)
$ id -a
uid=1005(tullyc) gid=1005(tullyc) groups=1005(tullyc),1003(tomcat)
```

but, I still cannot create directories!

```
$ ls -al /usr/share/tomcat9-root/webapps/
total 45128
drwxr-x--- 4 tomcat tomcat     4096 Jun 14 20:10 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 tomcat tomcat     4096 Jun 14 21:08 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 tullyc tullyc 46192111 Jun 14 20:10 radar.war
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root       4096 Jun 14 15:27 radar_data
drwxr-xr-x 3 tullyc tullyc     4096 Jun 14 15:28 radarui
```

Based on the directory listing, and output from `groups` and `id` this should work:

```
$ mkdir /usr/share/tomcat9-root/webapps/radar
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/share/tomcat9-root/webapps/radar': Permission denied
```

I initially tried just exiting my ssh session and starting a new one but still got permission denied. So, I took the sledgehammer approach (this is not my production server so I can reboot at will) and rebooted. Even after a reboot I still get the same answers from `groups` and `id` and still get permission denied.

I am puzzled because I was previously able to create files and directories in the `/usr/share/tomcat9-root/webapps` directory after setting it's owner and group to `tomcat:tomcat`.

So, having both logged out and logged back in and even rebooted the server, and showing that I have the proper groups and permissions, why can't I create files or directories?

Comment: Perhaps try `newgrp tomcat` before creating the directory?

Comment: `drwxr-x--- 4 tomcat tomcat     4096 Jun 14 20:10 .` says members of group `tomcat` don't have write permission in the current directory (which is `/usr/share/tomcat9-root/webapps/`), no?

Comment: DOH!!! Head slap! I was mis reading the directory listing!  I was confusing `.` and `..` and reading the permissions for `..` as the permissions for the current directory! Thanks @steeldriver